# How do you vertically center text within a bootstrap 4 button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've tried googling this question but I haven't found an answer yet. I'm working on a set of page controls and I'm having trouble getting my text to vertically center within the buttons.

Here's my html so far:

```
<div class="row input-group align-items-center justify-content-center" data-bind="visible: pageCount > 1">
  <button class="btn btn-sm mx-1" data-bind="click: gotoPage.bind($data, 0)">&laquo;</button>
  <button class="btn btn-sm mx-1" data-bind="click: gotoPage.bind($data, page() - 1)">&lsaquo;</button>
  <div class="ml-1" style="width:4rem">
    <input class="text-right form-control form-control-sm" type="number" data-bind="value: page" />
  </div>
  <span class="mx-1" data-bind="text: ' / ' + (pageCount) "></span>
  <button class="align-middle btn btn-sm mx-1" data-bind="click: gotoPage.bind($data, page() + 1)">&rsaquo;</button>
  <button class="btn btn-sm mx-1" data-bind="click: gotoPage.bind($data, pageCount)">&raquo;</button>
</div>
```

Those `data-bind` attrs are my knockout bindings fyi.

Here's what it's rendered as using Chrome:

[image]

As you can see, the guillemets are slightly below vertical center of the buttons. I've tried applying all the bootstrap vertical align classes I can think of (`align-items-center`, `align-middle`, `text-center`, etc) to the parent div and to the buttons, but have had no luck so far.

Comment: @Tegito123 `.text-center` doesn't seem to have any effect when applied to either the parent div or the buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in your HTML entities. it has by default space in it. see below example.

```css
.btn span {
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h3>With Html entity</h3>
  <button role="button" class="btn btn-sm mx-1 d-inline-flex align-items-center" data-bind="click: gotoPage.bind($data, 0)"><span>&laquo;<span></button>


<h3>Without Html entity</h3>
  <button role="button" class="btn btn-sm mx-1 d-inline-flex align-items-center" data-bind="click: gotoPage.bind($data, 0)"><span>A</span></button>
<button role="button" class="btn btn-sm mx-1 d-inline-flex align-items-center" data-bind="click: gotoPage.bind($data, 0)"><span>a</span></button>
```

Comment: I just tried both of your suggested methods and they had no effect. What tag would you recommend replacing the buttons with?

Comment: I will make demo for you. Wait for some time

Comment: hey @tom problem is in your HTML entities. it has by default space in it

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. Using a tall character like an uppercase 'A' just masks the issue. If you run the above snippet with a lowercase 'a', you'll see that it's not centered.

Comment: yeah it's depend on character line height

Answer (score 0):

I created an exact snippet with bootstrap-4 cdn and its looking fine, below is the snippet

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row input-group align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <button class="btn btn-sm mx-1"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i></button>
  <button class="btn btn-sm mx-1"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></button>
  <div class="ml-1" style="width:4rem">
    <input class="text-right form-control form-control-sm" type="number" />
  </div>
  <span class="mx-1"></span>
  <button class="align-middle btn btn-sm mx-1"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></button>
  <button class="btn btn-sm mx-1"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: The character in the buttons don't look vertically centered to me.

Comment: @Tom check this updated snippet, added font-awesome so you can customize the sizes

Comment: That looks nice and I appreciate the help, but it doesn't really answer my question of how to vertically center the characters I have. I'd rather not have to import all of font awesome just for this little thing.

Comment: I totally understand, and the problem is with the size of ascii characters you have. One solution would be placing them in span and scaling the span class. but again this solution needs lot of browser support optimization.